# WordPress - Get server time using ajax and admin-ajax.php

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am new to using Ajax to get WordPress data.
The following code should return the server time but the response always is "400 Bad Request".

```
$.ajax({
    url: obj + "?action=wps_get_time&format=U",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Also tried it as POST and it was the same.

```
$.ajax({
    url: obj,
    method: "post",
    data: { action: "wps_get_time", format: "U" },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Any suggestions what's wrong please? Can't figure.
I always thought there are actions I can use always such as wps_get_time, without using a plugin. Am I wrong?
Ist there any easy way to get the server time by ajax?
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will return server time in Indochina and log it to console.

````
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: location.href,
    complete: function (req, textStatus) {
      var dateString = req.getResponseHeader('Date');
      if (dateString.indexOf('GMT') === -1) {
        dateString += ' GMT';
      }
      var date = new Date(dateString);
      console.log(date);
    }
  });```
````

Comment: Thank you very much, this works as expected. To speed up the function I set up a dummy URL with almost no content. Great!